# Why is there no logical negation for atomic operations?

Tags: javascript, rust, bit-manipulation, atomic

[JavaScript has no](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Atomics) `Atomics.not`, but it does have operations like `Atomics.and`.

[Rust also has no](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/atomic/struct.AtomicI8.html) `fetch_not`, but it does have operations like `fetch_or`.

Why don't those languages have atomic logical negation operators, while they do have other common operations?

Comment: I don’t know if it’s *why*, but both of those have XOR, and you can XOR with an all-1-bits value for a bitwise NOT. (Did you mean bitwise instead of logical?)

Answer (score 3):

The x86 assembly for `fetch_or` looks like this (when the value is discarded):

```
lock
or byte ptr [rsp], 51
```

That's actually one instruction: `lock` is an instruction prefix that modifies the next instruction. Specifically, `lock` makes the instruction be executed atomically. [Intel's x86 manual](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf) specifies what instructions support the `lock` prefix. Bitwise `not` supports the `lock` prefix

> This instruction can be used with a LOCK prefix to allow the instruction to be executed atomically.

So if there's an x86 instruction for it, why isn't there an atomic operation for it? [LLVM](https://llvm.org/) doesn't have an intrinsic for it. In Rust, the `Atomic*` functions all forward directly to an LLVM intrinsic, so only the operations that had a corresponding LLVM intrinsic got a function. The memory model for JavaScript atomics ["takes significant inspiration from LLVM"](https://github.com/tc39/ecmascript_sharedmem/blob/5acab4636ead3cc9fe13b0d97a40c7dadab2fed9/LLVM_LIKE.md), so it doesn't seem like a stretch to guess that the `Atomics` functions were just copied from what LLVM had.

[LLVM supports 6 intrinsic operations](https://llvm.org/docs/Atomics.html#libcalls-atomic): `add`, `sub`, `and`, `or`, `xor`, and `nand`. It supports those ones because [GCC has intrinsic operations with the same names](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Atomic/GCCMM/LIbrary#line-238) (except for the type). Atomic `and`, `sub`, `and`, `or`, and `xor` operations [were added to GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/pipermail/gcc-patches/2011-August/320670.html) ([`nand` was added later](https://gcc.gnu.org/pipermail/gcc-patches/2011-September/323038.html)) as a part of adding support for `std::atomic` in C++11.

C++11 has 5 bitwise atomic operations in `std::atomic`: add, sub, and, or, xor. (but not nand, which gets an intrinsic in GCC but no actual support in `std::atomic`). Why? Because that is what was suggested in the [2007 paper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2324.html) originally proposing atomics in C++, which defines the operations "fetch-and-{add,sub,and,or,xor}". They don't provide a reason for only having those 5 operations, but my guess is that they wanted to minimise the amount of implementation work for compiler implementors, since you can get a NOT operation by XORing against all ones. Or maybe they just didn't think about it.

Comment: The assembly for `fetch_or` you've shown can only be used when the fetched value is discarded. If it is not, `fetch_or` has to be implemented with `cmpxchg` loop.